# C# Problem with collection of custom classes

Tags: c#

In my application I have robots that the user can give any number of different tasks to do. Each task is a class derived from the abstract class Task:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    string description = "default description";
    ...
}

public class Walk : Task
{
    string description = "Do walk";
    ...
}

public class Talk : Task
{
    string description = "Do talk";
    ...
}
```

So each robot has a collection of these tasks. The collection is defined like this:

```
public class TaskCollection
{
    List<Task> _collection = new List<Task>();

    public void AddTask(string taskName)
    {
        _collection.Add( (Task)Activator.CreateInstance(null, taskName).Unwrap() );
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _collection.Count;
    }

    public Task GetElement( int i )
    {
        return _collection[i];
    }
}
```

So to test it out I create a TaskCollection and add some tasks like this:

```
public TaskCollection tasks = new TaskCollection();
tasks.AddTask( "Walk" );
tasks.AddTask( "Talk" );
```

And then this code to show all the tasks that have been added:

```
for( int i = 0; i < tasks.Count(); i++ )
{
    print( tasks.GetElement(i).description );
}
```

For each task it prints out "default description" rather than the descriptions assigned in the inherited classes. Is this because i'm casting the class instance as a Task? If i remove that cast I get this error:

The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(Task)' has some invalid arguments.

Hopefully its clear what I'm trying to do here. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's because you are returning them as `Task`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring extra variables in each subclass, but then you're always *printing* the `description` variable from task. The subclass variables only *hide* the variable in `Task`.

There are two (or more) options here.

First, you could use polymorphism:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    public virtual string Description { get { return "default description"; } }
}

public class Walk : Task
{
    public virtual string Description { get { return "Do walk"; } }
}
```

This makes a lot of sense if in reality instead of "description" you're actually wanting some *behaviour* which will change in each concrete implementation.

The other option is to keep a single description in `Task`, but pass the value for it into the constructor:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    private readonly string description;

    protected Task(string description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

public class Walk : Task
{
    public Walk() : base("Do walk")
    {
    }
}
```

Now you *could* set the field directly from the subclass if you made it accessible, but I would strongly advise you to keep it private. If you *really* want to "push" new values, make it a property like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public string Description { get; protected set; }
}
```

That allows subclasses to set the description, but from the outside it can only be fetched.

Answer (score 2):

Following is not right:

```
public class Walk : Task
{
    string description = "Do walk";
    ...
}
```

You are hiding `Task`'s description member by declaring a new member named description in it's child class. You must be getting warnings stating this.

Instead, use a constructor like following:

```
public class Walk : Task
{
    public Walk()
    {
        description = "Do walk";
    }
}
```

and also make *description* protected in Task class.

```
protected string description = "...";
```

On a side note, if you put following code in your loop, you will get correct type names:

```
print( tasks.GetElement(i).GetType().FullName );
```

Following is a good article explaining what is going on there (Member hiding):

[Polymorphism, Method Hiding and Overriding in C#](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html)

Comment: I edited your answer not to redefine the string in the constructor ;)

Comment: Isn't polymorphism better solution?

Comment: FYI, he's creating a new *field* not a new *property*. Also, while the constructor approach is a *better design*, it doesn't address his question.

Comment: @rotman: I would not use polymorphism in *this specific scenario*.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I thought you just suggested using polymorphism in your answer below :)

Comment: @Adam: Corrected. And I tried to address the question `Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?`. I pointed out what is going wrong and also suggested how to fix it.

Comment: @rotman: I answered the OP's specific question about why his (by his assumption, polymorphic) approach wasn't working. In the latter part of my answer, I advise him to take a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for this. All makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You're using fields, rather than properties. Among other issues, *fields cannot be polymorphic*. Polymorphism is the effect you're seeking, where a member is defined at a high level and its implementation is provided (or overridden) at a lower level.

What you want are *properties*. Since this is an exercise in OO design, I'll keep things as you have it:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    public virtual string Description
    {
        get { return "default description"; }
    }
    ...
}

public class Walk : Task
{
    public overrides string Description
    { 
        get { return "Do walk"; }
    }
    ...
}

public class Talk : Task
{
    public overrides string Description
    { 
        get { return "Do talk"; }
    }
    ...
}
```

What you accomplished with the fields was simply providing a member of the same name, which hides the higher-level member from the outward-facing API of the lower-level class. If you were to reference the instance as `Walk` or `Talk` (through casting, for example), then you would see the appropriate description. But when you reference it as a general `Task`, the more-defined members are unknown.

Bear in mind that I'm *answering the question you asked*, which is why it wasn't working and how to make it work. This is not the design I would have chosen for this particular task, since you aren't providing different *functionality* in the derived classes (for this property), just different *data*. Given that, I would have created a constructor argument that takes the description, then returns it in the base class.

```
public abstract class Task
{
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    protected Task(string description)
    {
        this.Description = description;
    }
}
```

Then the derived classes would look like:

```
public class Walk : Task
{
    public Walk() : base("Do walk") { }
}
```

(etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do this

```
public abstract class Task
{
    string description = "default description";
    ...
}

public class Walk : Task
{
    string description = "Do walk";
    ...
}
```

It should look like this

```
public class Walk : Task
{
   public Walk
   {
      description = "Do walk";
   }
}
```

That should set the field in the base class, right now you aren't actually doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
public abstract class Task
{
    private const string description = "default description";
    public virtual string Description { get { return description; } }
}

public class Walk : Task
{
    private const string description = "Do walk";
    public override string Description { get { return description; } }
}
```